# How can i make my bot respond with a react for every action for my help command . discord.js

Tags: discord.js

i don't know how to make my bot to react with a white check mark after the author receiving the message and also reacting with a cross mark when the author doesn't receive the message in dms. this is my code:

```
client.on('message', message => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;
    if (message.content.startsWith(prefix + 'help')) {
        const founder = client.users.get('my id');
        message.author.send(`
[❖---------- there's a room called log ----------❖]
1-  fast connection host
2-  easy commands
3- ⚠️ working on it everyday
4-  free for anyone
5- ⚛️ anti-hack
6- Made by one developer : ${founder.username}#${founder.discriminator}
`);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`User.send()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=send) returns a Promise that gets fulfilled when the message is sent correctly and gets rejected when the bot is unable to send it: you can use `Promise.then()` and `Promise.catch()` to perform different actions based on what happened.
Here's an example:

```js
client.on('message', message => {
  if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return
  if (message.content.startsWith(prefix + 'help')) {
    message.author.send('Your message').then(dmMessage => {
      // The message has been sent correctly, you can now react to your original message with the tick
      message.react('✔️')
    }).catch(error => {
      // There has been some kind of problem, you should react with the cross
      message.react('❌')
    })
  }
})
```

Comment: I did '()' instead of 'dmMessage' and 'error' to not count as unused var but it worked well.

Comment: Sure, you did the right thing if you don't plan to use those, I put them there just so you know that you can use them if you need to ;)

Answer (score 0):

Basically, if it fails to send in somebody's DM, it will throw an error. Therefore, to react with a cross mark if they don't receive it, just catch the error like so.

```js
client.on('message', message => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;
    if (message.content.startsWith(prefix + 'help')) {
        const founder = client.users.get('my id');
        try {
            message.author.send(`
[❖---------- there's a room called log ----------❖]
1-  fast connection host
2-  easy commands
3- ⚠️ working on it everyday
4-  free for anyone
5- ⚛️ anti-hack
6- Made by one developer : ${founder.username}#${founder.discriminator}
`);
            message.react('✅');
        } catch {
            message.react('❌');
        }
    }
});
```

Here, if the DM sends, it reacts with a check mark, and if an error is thrown (it happens when it isn't sent) it reacts with a cross mark.

Hope this helps.